# Can this be reduced to a single query?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a field `position = PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)`. Given an instance of this model, I want to get the instance with the next highest position (subject to certain filters). If this instance is the one with the highest position, I want to wrap around to 0 and return the instance with the lowest position; if this instance is the only one, I want to return itself.

Here's my code:

```
count = Player.objects.count()
return Player.objects.filter(game_id=self.game_id, is_alive=True).annotate(
    relative_position=(F('position') - self.position - 1 + count) % count
).order_by('relative_position')[:1].get()
```

(The reason for the `+ count` is because a negative number modulo a positive one is negative in SQL.)

This requires two database queries. I suspect that it's possible to do it in just one query, using `annotate` and `Count`, but I haven't figured out exactly how to put such a query together. Can it be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that conditional query expressions are a thing in Django 1.8, which meant I could abandon modulo arithmetic and do this:

```
return Player.objects.filter(game_id=self.game_id, is_alive=True).order_by(
    Case(When(position__gt=self.position, then=Value(0)), default=Value(1)),
    'position'
)[:1].get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not always exactly one query, but it probably beats 2 queries and annotations:

```
players = Player.objects.filter(game_id=self.game_id, is_alive=True).order_by('position')
try:
    return players.filter(position__lt=self.position)[0]
except IndexError:
    return players.last()
```